# html form: prevent re-submitting while sending

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit, enter

I have this form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="my_form">
    <input type="text" name="my_input">
</form>
```

You can write some text and the submit by pressing the enter key.

My problem: When you press the enter key multiple times, it'll also sent multiple times to my server.

There are solution like this:

```
onsubmit="my_button=true;return true;"
```

But these solutions require a submit button.

Is there a way to do this without adding a (hidden) submit button?

Comment: Set the input field to disabled?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, but how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be absolutely sure, for example, submitting the form twice can cause severe damage/cause malicious things to happen, then you need to check this serverside. One rule of webdevelopment and general development is to never trust your end-user, and by simply blocking the form using JavaScript, you cannot be assured that a malicious user won't be sending the form twice by getting around the JavaScript.

What you can do is something like this:

**Important:** This is just a proof of concept example to explain the idea, this is **not** a 100% bulletproof solution.

**Form**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['nonce'] = random_number();
?>
<html>
...
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nonce']; ?>" />
... other form elements ...
</form>
...
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$nonce = isset($_POST['nonce']) ? (int)$_POST['nonce'] : 0;
$session_nonce = $_SESSION['nonce'];

if ($_SESSION['nonce'] != $nonce) {
    die("Invalid nonce, double submission detected.");
}

$_SESSION['nonce'] += 1; // this will cause the previous check to fail on a second submission.
```

Answer (score 1):

some like this :

```
 <form onsubmit="send();" method="post" name="my_form">
    <input type="submit" name="my_input" id="sub">
 </form>
```

js code:

```
function send(){
    $("#sub").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax({
        // data
        success: function(data){
            $("#sub").attr('disabled', false);
        }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this (untestet):

```
    var formSubmitted = false;
    document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', function(){
    if(formSubmitted === false) {
        formSubmitted = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button once it's set so the User cannot click it again

```
<form action="" method="post" name="my_form">
    <input type="text" name="my_input" <?php if(isset($_POST['my_input'])) { print 
    'disabled'; } ?>>
</form>
```

Comment: This will not prevent the user from using developers console in his browser and removing the `disabled` attribute.